# AngularJS Service not Returning JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to pull json data from the angular service but its always printing blank spaces, can some one help me please. No errors in the console as well.

**Service**

```
    app.service("Java4sService", function() {

     var details = {};
     this.details = function() {

         [{
             name: "James",
             country: "United Stages"
         }, {
             name: "Rose",
             country: "United Kingdom"
         }, {
             name: "Smith",
             country: "United States"
         }]

     };

     this.getDetails = function() {
         return details;
     };

 });
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("Java4sController",function($scope,Java4sService){           
                $scope.personDetails = Java4sService.getDetails();
});
```

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in personDetails ">
            {{person.name}} - {{person.country}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem is that in your service you are setting 'this.details' to a function which returns nothing.
Look at your function more carefully again. 
As the answer recommends remove the function surrounding the array and then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your service as below:

```
app.service("Java4sService", function() {
    var details = [ {
        name: "James",
        country: "United Stages"
    }, {
        name: "Rose",
        country: "United Kingdom"
    }, {
        name: "Smith",
        country: "United States"
    } ]

    return {
        getDetails: function() {
            return details;
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsgqn17q/)

Comment: I am using service, not factory.   So we should use this.getDetails i guess.

Comment: One more thing.., what the difference between..
getDetails = function() {}  and getDetails:function() {} ?

Comment: `getDetails = function()...` means you assign a `Function` object to variable `getDetails`. `{ getDetails: function()... }` means you assign a `Function` object to property `getDetails` of an object.